# MySQL Log of invalid Queries

Tags: sql, mysql, view, logging

I AM NOT RUNNING THE COMMANDS FROM PHP!

I have MySQL log_error value set to /var/log/mysql/error.log

However when I connect to a database and run an SQL command, the error does not appear in the log.

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table
where this_is_invalid_and_will_fail="Doesn't matter because column doesn't exist!";
```

There are commands running from some sort of windows application. All I want to know is what invalid commands its sending to the MySQL server so that I can attempt to resolve them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Error log doesn't do that:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log.html

> The error log contains information
>   indicating when mysqld was started and
>   stopped and also any critical errors
>   that occur while the server is
>   running.

MySQL doesn't log invalid/failed queries anywhere.

---

If it's for debugging purposes, you might try setting up a MySQL Proxy, which could log this I think:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/

Comment: Thanks for the snippet of the documentation. Also, the MySQL proxy thing looks neat, to bad its not more developed at this time.

Comment: Thanks for that tip... Finally a useful answer... All the answers I came across so far where either "it can't be done" or "do it in your application".
Anyway the above link is outdated, so this is the current one, it seems:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/

Comment: @Rolf: thanks for pointing out, I've updated the link in my answer.

Comment: What a questionable design decision. With ORMs or mappers, this introduces unnecessary hassle

Answer (score 16):

Basically, there are 2 ways.

1) setup some kind of proxy, which can log error queries. There are a lot of forks of the original mysql proxy (which was mentioned by @Mchl) - https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=MySQL+Proxy Also you can find latest version of the original mysql proxy here https://github.com/mysql/mysql-proxy

I dont like this way, because its kind of too complicated for quick debug

2) you can enable general log in mysql (which will log ALL queries).
It will create big overhead and doesnt fit production requirements, but its fast and easy way to fix bugs in development environment.

Just login to your mysql and execute

`SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'general_log%';`

You will see logs location, like

`+------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                  |
+------------------+------------------------+
| general_log      | OFF                    |
| general_log_file | /mnt/ssd/mysql/s.log   |
+------------------+------------------------+`

After that execute 

 `mysqladmin flush-logs -u root -p`

When you will need to stop logs - just execute

`SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';`

Comment: The second version will not write out syntax errors

Comment: So elegant solution

Comment: if needed `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin flush-logs -u root -p`

Answer (score 5):

As of mysql version 5.6.3 (released 2011-10-03), there is a variable called `log-raw` which allows you to include invalid queries in the general query log:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-raw

You will need to turn on general query log using `general-log` and `general-log-file`, e.g.:

```
[mysqld]
general-log=1
log-raw=1
general-log-file=/var/log/mysql/general.log
```

Comment: "allows you to include invalid queries in the general query log". This is **incorrect** - the documentation specifically mentions `log-raw` is to reveal masked passwords, and nothing more.

Comment: @MartinKonecny, using `log-raw` solved the issue for me -- did it not work for you?  I believe the reason it works is that for mysql to mask passwords, it needs to be able to parse the query.  So if it's unable to parse a query, it doesn't log anything which makes it impossible to detect such queries by looking at the mysql log file.   This is where `log-raw` comes to rescue.

Comment: Not sure why according to the doc, but indeed, `log_raw=1
general_log=1
general_log_file=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.query.log` worked for me too on MySQL 5.7.16

Answer (score 3):

Could you enable the [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html)? That should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: general log is useful. but it does not tell me which commands did not run successfully. For example, I just moved MySQL from windows to linux and experienced an issue with capitalization that did not occur on windows. Something that is completely impossible to tell using general query log. ( unless you can correct me of course. )

Comment: So search the log for unique `SELECT` queries (`grep -i select host_name.log | sort | uniq`), run them from a script, and see which ones fail.

Comment: The General Query log only logs queries that complete successfully. This question is about the ones that don't.

Comment: @muttonUp: that's not true, the General Query Log records every statement received by the server before it is executed.See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html.

Comment: Doesn't say "before execution" anywhere or anything about errors being logged. I've used the GQL for years to debug, and it has never written the errors. Try turning it on and entering some random string in the client...nothing...

Comment: @muttonUp: The OP's example *does* appear in the log. The question is about valid SQL statements with invalid column names, not invalid SQL statements.

Comment: @muttonUp: And in any case, invalid SQL statements *do* appear in the log.

Comment: I concede that some invalid statements do appear. But Try the OPs query before selecting a database or try this "selectx * from any_table where field=1". Neither will show.

Comment: @muttonUp: If you haven't selected a database, the client will not send the statement to the server, it will raise an error itself. That's why it doesn't appear in the log, and bad statements that never reach the server are not a problem. Your second example does work for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is not so trivial. The best way to do this, is to log bad queries in your application. There is no built-in way.

Comment: Its not my application. It is some sort of windows application that I have no access to.